# Poisson probability lost sales?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

"Assume that a monthly demand X is Poisson distributed with a mean of 200.
Given that a grocery store  can only place an order at the beginning of a month, how many item should be ordered to make the expected lost sales less than 10."

Not sure how to start this question.
I know that X~poisson(200)
So on average the demand is 200.

And if for example we order 220 but the demand is 230 we would have 10 lost sales.

So I can make a random variable $L$ be lost sales but not sure how that would be distributed.

I know for example if we order 220

then we have $P(X>220)=1-F(220)=1-.924=.075$ of demand being bigger than the order.

Comment: You need the expected number of lost sales, not the probability.  Given that you order $220$....What is the probability that you lose $0$?  Exactly $1$?  And so on.

Comment: I see so its like if I order 220 and the demand is 221 I would lose 1 and if its 222 I would lose 2. Not sure how I would calculate the probability

Comment: I think the the prob of 2 lost sales would be same thing as having
prob 221 demand right with poisson distribution.

Comment: Do you agree that the remaining stock after n days is $m\cdot \left(1-\sum\limits_{x=0}^n P(X=x)\right)$, where m are the number of ordered items and $X\sim Poi(200)$?

Comment: @FernandoMartinez  Yes, for a fixed supply you can compute the probability of getting any particular loss, and can therefore get the expected loss.  I think you'l find that $220$ is too big a supply, but of course you can adjust the supply.

Comment: @callculus42
Not sure. Like the way I am thinking is like this say I ordered 210 and I have demand of 211,212,213,214 then I would have the lost sales is 1,2,3,4 and then I would for example 
E(L)=1*P(x=211)+2*P(x=212) and keep going  
and keep trying different fixed order until I get E(L)<10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining

$L(Q)=\max\{X-Q,0\},$

the expected loss is given by

$$\mathbb E (L(Q))=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \max\{i-Q,0\} \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}=\sum_{i=Q}^{\infty} (i-Q)\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}=\color{blue}{\lambda -Q + \sum_{i=0}^{Q-1} (Q-i)\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}.}$$

This can be used to find values of $Q$ for which $$\mathbb E (L(Q)) \le 10.$$

For $\lambda=200$, the range is obtained as $$Q \ge m=193.$$ Note that the expectation $\mathbb E (L(Q))$ is decreasing in $Q$.

**Remark 1:** For computing the summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{Q-1} (Q-i)\frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}=\sum_{i=0}^{Q-1} (Q-i) \mathbb P (X=i)$$

each probability needs to be recursively computed as

$$\mathbb P (X=i)=\frac{\lambda}{i} \mathbb P (X=i-1), \, i \ge 1$$

with $\mathbb P (X=0)=e^{-\lambda} $ for computational stability.

**Remark 2:** To find $m$,  the direct search method is used by noting that

$$m \ge \lambda - 10.$$

So for $\lambda=200$, the start point of the direct search for finding $m$ is $200 - 10=190$.